# Is there a way to force Bazel to run tests serially

Tags: gpu, tensorflow, bazel

By default, Bazel runs tests in a parallel fashion to speed things up. However, I have a resource (GPU) that can't handle parallel jobs due to the GPU memory limit. Is there a way to force Bazel to run tests in a serial, i.e., non-parallel way?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm building TensorFlow and as a part of that I run the unit tests in the source code. Under the GPU build mode, many of those unit tests will run on GPU. When they run in parallel, I sometimes get GPU OOM errors. Thos e errors don't occur when I ran the tests one by one, manually. But it's a pain and not scalable to run tests manually.

Comment: Does passing `--jobs=1` to the `bazel test` command work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`--jobs 1` will limit the number of parallel jobs Bazel runs to 1.

You can also modify the test targets and add `tags = ["exclusive"]` to prevent specific test to run in parallel (see https://bazel.build/reference/test-encyclopedia).

Comment: I think when one uses the `"exclusive"` tag, needs to be aware also that the test results won't be cached. So in circumstances like CI's it can cause a performance.

Comment: @Sambatyon, that's not true according to the docs, I think you're thinking of the `"external"` flag

Comment: I'd recommend against this approach (`--jobs` or `exclusive` tag) and instead use https://stackoverflow.com/a/70084246/856336.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`--local_test_jobs=1`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--local_test_jobs) to only run a single test target at a time locally.

> The max number of local test jobs to run concurrently. Takes an integer, or a keyword ("auto", "HOST_CPUS", "HOST_RAM"), optionally followed by an operation ([-|*]) eg. "auto", "HOST_CPUS*.5". 0 means local resources will limit the number of local test jobs to run concurrently instead. Setting this greater than the value for --jobs is ineffectual

- `tags = ["exclusive"]` has [other complications to consider with respect to caching](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3791) (but [this issue is fixed in Bazel 7+](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/23580aaee7d040d7bff49c68ac0d8dfa7333225b)).
- `--jobs` will serialize the entire build process, not just testing, so it's less than ideal.

Comment: An important effect of doing this is: if you set --local_test_jobs to a larger number than 5, (if you had 5 GPUs for example), it runs 5 local tests regardless of if RAM and CPU resources are available. It effectively ignores "cpu:x" tags.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 resources Bazel will respect limitations upon: RAM and CPU. You may hijack one (Probably RAM) to represent GPU(s) as they're available to a run and required by a test. (I've stopped short of doing this for a limited hardware resource because it feels to inelegant, but I can't think of a reason it shouldn't work.)

Comment: While the API still makes affordances to set IO limits they aren't respected by tests, which also allow for limits of tests jobs. Setting --local_test_jobs will cause bazel to ignore limitations based on resources.

Answer (score 0):

[Future releases of Bazel should support extra resources like GPUs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/2b2bea4ee9d51ad875a8d273aa344ac9c5b6742c)

and releases that contain that change should support extra resource tags like "resources:GPU:1" when --local_extra_resources=gpu=1 is set. This should enable GPU tests to be bound by a limited quantity of GPUs, and for them to run non-exclusively and without limiting the total number of --jobs or "test_jobs"